# Chrome won't debug a large JS file

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a large Javascript file (20,000 lines).

The Chrome debugger won't debug it. I.e. I can put in a break point and it knows about the break point but it won't pause on it. This is definitely to do with the large file size; it work with smaller files on the same site.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get it to work with this large file? (I'm unable to do anything about the large file size).

Comment: Sounds like a bug; please, file it to [chromium bugtracker](http://bugs.chromium.org)

Comment: have the same issue with 50k +

Comment: @AndreyLushnikov has a bug been reported?

Comment: @FutuToad I haven't seen any; would be great to have it filed though :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the following alternative:

- Copy the script
- Add a [debugger statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/0bwt76sk)
- Paste into the console
- Run the script

**References**

- [DevTools: [console] feature: force enable strict-mode for console evaluations](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=464749)
- [Console: Handle object literals](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=499864)
- [ES6 template literal support in DevTools](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=439079)
- [Chromium Design Documents: Site Isolation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/site-isolation)