# Getting Chrome to hit breakpoints after thousands of lines

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I can't seem to get Chrome to hit breakpoints past line 50000, in Firebug they are hit fine.

Is there anything I can do to help this?

Comment: Maybe it is obvious, but split the file in smaller parts? Isn't it a pain to program in a file with so many lines? Don't solve the problem but avoid it.

Comment: @A1rPun its out of my control right now..

Comment: I see. There is a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284223/chrome-wont-debug-a-large-js-file

Comment: Have you tried to add the keyword debugger in your file? Maybe it halts the running: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger